# How to set a property on WPF ComboBoxItem only when it is the selected item and it satisfies condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, itemtemplate

I am having trouble making a combo box item appear with the font color red only when it is the selected item AND its underlying ID matches the last ID in the ItemSource.  Here's what i've got so far, this makes it red only when it is the selected item, but how do i also check to see if the underlying property "ID" matches the last entry in the ObservableCollection that contains it, ie only when SelectedItem's ID== Collection[Length-1].ID?

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding BillingCycles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBillingCycle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BillingCycleDescription}" >
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsCurrentCycleColorConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

So, if SelectedBillingCycle.ID != BillingCycles[BillingCycle.Length-1].ID, the text should appear red.  I'm not sure how I'd refer to the BillingCycles[BillingCycles.Length-1] to compare it to.

///EDIT:

Changed the XAML, this is getting closer but changes ALL the comboBoxItems, not just the selectedItem.  I'm thinking I need to use a template selector of some kind or rethink the XAML completely.

Comment: looks like you have to use a `Converter` to convert the `ID` to `true` (by comparing against `BillingCycles[BillingCycle.Length-1].ID` (that `Converter` is for the Binding in `Condition`).

Comment: ok but how do i specify the ID AND of the SelectedItem AND the ID of the BillingCycles[BillingCycles.Length-1] to the converter?

Comment: Maybe I need to have two templates?  Since i want only the SelectedItem to ever turn red, not the other items in the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : Suppose i have a UserType class

```
public class UserType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and I have ObservableCollection of UserType binded to itemsSource of ComboBox

```
public ObservableCollection<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
```

> xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:ComboBoxForegroundConverter x:Key="ComboConv"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ComboConv}">
                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                    <Binding/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</StackPanel>
```

> MultiValueConverter

```
    public class ComboBoxForegroundConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Count() == 3)
        {
            var itemsSource = values[0] as ObservableCollection<UserType>;//This is the Type of you Collection binded to ItemsSource
            if (itemsSource != null && itemsSource.Any() && itemsSource.Last() == values[1] && values[2]==values[1])
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your case DisplayMember path will be BillingCycleDescription.

Comment: this is pretty close, but it turn every ComboBoxItem red (or black).  How can i only change the color of the SelectedItem (ComboBoxItem that is currently selected) red?

Comment: ok i got that but Do you want ComboBox Foreground Red when last item is selected?

Comment: i want only the ComboBoxItem that is the current SelectedItem to change its foreground to red, if it meets the condition

Comment: for var comboboxItem i always get null instead of comboboxitem because values[2] is "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}"

Comment: I have tested it working fine . make sure you dont set any path in last binding which is of Comboboxitem relativesource

Comment: i edited my complete xaml above for you to see, i don't know why but it always has values[2] as unset value

Comment: This is strange it is working fine with me but any ways i updated the answer . try this here we will use direct Binding.

Comment: ok but this still changes the color of ALL the comboboxitems.  i only want to change the selected item, the others should always be black.  only the selected item should ever be red, and only when its ID matches the condition

Comment: i think you are still stuck on ComboBox foreground, whereas i want Selected ComboBoxItem foreground

Comment: Question states only turn the font red when it is the selected item AND when the ID passes the given condition

Comment: I have Updated the Xaml Try this. and about ID you can cast the values  and compare ID like  itemsSource.Last().ID == values[1].ID  but yu need to cast itemsSource.Last() and values

Comment: this turns the comboboxitems in the drop down red, NOT the selected item

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to use a DataTemplateSelector class to differentiate between the SelectedItem and other comboboxItems:

```
public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DropDownTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = container.GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>();
        if (comboBoxItem == null)
        {
            return SelectedTemplate;
        }
        return DropDownTemplate;
    }
}
```

and this extension class:

```
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : Visual
    {
        while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
        {
            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        }

        return child as T;
    }
```

and here is the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding BillingCycles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBillingCycle}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
                    <b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BillingCycleDescription}">
                                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsCurrentCycleColorConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
                    <b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BillingCycleDescription}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
                </b:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ComboBox>
```

and use this converter, which i figured out using help from Ethicallogics:

```
public class IsCurrentCycleColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        if (values != null && values.Count() == 2)
        {
            var itemsSource = values[0] as ObservableCollection<BillingCycle>;//This is the Type of you Collection binded to ItemsSource
            if (!(itemsSource != null && itemsSource.Any() && itemsSource.First() == (BillingCycle)values[1]))
            {
                color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
            }
        }

        return color;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad finally you got it done . i was in office so wasnt able to reply.

Comment: yeah, seems like a ridiculous amount of changes for s small thing.  anyway, thanks for the help!